# Adding a string before and after a word in text in Python

Tags: python

I have list of entities and a text.Like this:

```
List=["Data Scientist", "Bihar", "Krishna"]
```

Text=" I am Krishna. I am from Bihar. I want to be a Data Scientist"

I want results like:

```
"I am [Entity]Krishna[Entity]. I am from [Entity]Bihar[Entity] . I want to be a [Entity]Data Scientist[Entity]"
```

Please help me with code in python to get this result.

Comment: You should at least show your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: The answer is in front of you, because your list contains everything you need.

Comment: You can use Python's f-Strings like this

`f"I am {List[2]}. I am from {List[1]}. I want to be a {List[0]}"`

Then you can just prepend or append according to your use-case.

Comment: I'm not sure people are correctly reading what is being asked...

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your problem. The best way to do that is to include the **text** based version of the code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.  If you want some help getting started, a simple solution might be one that iterates over items in `Lists` and uses `Text.replace()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use re.sub() with a pattern built from your list of keywords:

```
import re
entities = ["Data Scientist", "Bihar", "Krishna"]
pattern  = r"\b("+"|".join(map(re.escape,sorted(entities,key=len)[::-1]))+r")\b"


test   = " I am Krishna. I am from Bihar. I want to be a Data Scientist"
result = re.sub(pattern,r"[entity]\1[entity]",test)

print(result)
I am [entity]Krishna[entity]. I am from [entity]Bihar[entity]. I want to be a [entity]Data Scientist[entity]
```

The search pattern is build by combining the keywords with the pipe operator (`|`) and enclosing that in a capture group for word boundaries:

```
'\b(Data Scientist|Krishna|Bihar)\b'
```

The longer keywords are placed first because the pipe operator is not greedy and, if you have keywords that are prefixes of longer keywords, you'll want the longer keyword to take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorry for misreading your original intent.  You can do this fairly easily by looking for each list item in your string and replacing it, like so:

```
List=["Data Scientist", "Bihar", "Krishna"]
text = ' I am Krishna. I am from Bihar. I want to be a Data Scientist'

for entity in List:
    if entity in List:
        text = text.replace(entity,'[Entity]'+entity+'[Entity]')
        
print(text)
```

Output:

```
 I am [Entity]Krishna[Entity]. I am from [Entity]Bihar[Entity]. I want to be a [Entity]Data Scientist[Entity]
```

If you're trying to be xml-like, the closing tag should have a slash - [/Entity]

Answer (score 0):

Using f-string is the way to go in your situation. This should do.

```
List=["Data Scientist", "Bihar", "Krishna"]
text=f'I am {List[0]}. I am from {List[1]}'
print(text)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: They are not seeking to reconstruct `Text`. They want to flag "entities" in `Text`. See their desired output : `I am [Entity]Krishna[Entity]....`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
List=["Data Scientist", "Bihar", "Krishna"]

print(f"I am {List[2]}. I am from {List[1]}. I want to be a {List[0]}")
```

As a general point, `List` is not a recommended name for a variable in python, as it is so close to the word `list` which has a particular meaning.

You might also consider a dictionary for this style of data where you are querying your object for specific, unordered values.

Comment: They are not seeking to reconstruct `Text`. They want to flag "entities" in `Text`. See their desired output : `I am [Entity]Krishna[Entity]....`